# Convert object to array and group them by object key

Tags: javascript

Convert object to array and group theme by keys! (I'm not really sure if the title is right but here is what I need:

(need to ckeck if current key equal next key +1 and equal to prev key -1 and they all have the same value!)

input like this

```
{  
    "2019-07-17":{  
      "7":66,
      "8":66,
      "9":66,
      "11":70,
      "12":70,
      "16":70
   },
   "2019-07-18":{  
      "10":68,
      "11":68,
      "12":75,
      "14":75,
      "15":75,
      "18":70
   }
}
```

output should be like this

```
{  
   "2019-07-17":[  
      {  
         "start":7,
         "end":9,
         "id":66
      },
      {  
         "start":11,
         "end":12,
         "id":70
      },
      {  
         "start":16,
         "end":17,
         "id":70
      }
   ],
   "2019-07-18":[  
      {  
         "start":10,
         "end":11,
         "id":68
      },
      {  
         "start":12,
         "end":13,
         "id":75
      },
      {  
         "start":14,
         "end":15,
         "id":75
      },
      {  
         "start":18,
         "end":19,
         "id":70
      }

   ]
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried and where you are running into problems. Objective here is for others to help you fix your code and it is expected you show attempts to solve your own issue

Comment: can you explain a bit more? what does start and end is referring here

Comment: start refer to the first key in object that mutch the same value of the end key

Comment: if there is no end key so the end should be start key + 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could group the entries with the inner key and value and get new objects.

```js
var data = { "2019-07-17": { 7: 66, 8: 66, 9: 66, 11: 70, 12: 70, 16: 70 }, "2019-07-18": { 10: 68, 11: 68, 12: 75, 14: 75, 15: 75, 18: 70 } },
    result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).map(([k, v]) => {
        var values = Object.entries(v).reduce((r, [l, id], i, { [i - 1]: last }) => {
            if (last && +last[0] + 1 === +l && last[1] === id) {
                r[r.length - 1].end = +l;
            } else {
                r.push({ start: +l, end: +l + 1, id });
            }
            return r;
        }, []);
        return [k, values];
    }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Nina this is exactly what I need (y)